# locating friends using GPS in Android

Tags: java, android

hi stackoverflow friends

I have an app for that I need to locate my friends location.Can anyone give me some sample code or tips. I found lot of articles but all of them telling about their current location. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to ask for cheap sample code you can copy and paste. If you want to have advice on the broad architecture for the app you are planing state this in your question. If you have a problem with the code you did already ask a specific question. But please don't ask questions without doing any work on your side.

Comment: hi man i'm just asking some tips for getting started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convince your friends to install your app, which uploads the location of the user to a server (with their consent, of course).